# What browsers support the jquery promise stuff?

Tags: jquery

What browsers support the jQuery promise stuff?

I can't seem to find the info on the jQuery site.

Comment: http://jquery.com/browser-support/  *All* jQuery features are designed to work in all browsers that version of jQuery supports.

Comment: That's an internal jquery object, it isn't subject to browser support.

Comment: Regular Javascript works on any browser that properly supports Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`jQuery Deffered`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) pattern was introduce in `jQuery 1.5`. So it works where `jQuery` 1.6 and new `1.*.*` versions [works](http://jquery.com/browser-support/):

1. Internet Explorer 6+
2. Chrome (Current - 1) or Current
3. Firefox (Current - 1) or Current
4. Safari 5.1+
5. Opera 12.1x, (Current - 1) or Current

But I remember that `1.5` must works in:

1. Internet Explorer 6+
2. Chrome All
3. Firefox 3+
4. Safari 3+
5. Opera 10.5+

Also jQuery `1.*.*` works(from my experience):

1. Android 2.1 Mobile Safari +
2. OperaMini 7+

Comment: Any browser, that uses 99% of Internet users

Comment: any browser that is in the list of supported browsers (i wouldn't consider IE6/7/8 modern)

Comment: Just a quick note: JQuery promises are supported by IE 6+, but javascript promises are not supported by IE at all. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility