# Get data outside function childrened get method

Tags: jquery, get

Hi there i have followed code, but i don't get returned data outside function.

```
function get() {
    $.get( 'data.json', function( d ) {
        return d;
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('err');
    });
}

console.log(get());
```

output: undefined

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is asynchronous Js

```
function get() {
    return $.get( 'data.json', function( d ) {
        return d;
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log('err');
    });
}

get().then((data)=>console.log(data))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, where i learn browser support for this structure ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585503/what-browsers-support-the-jquery-promise-stuff